# Added a unique index, but cannot find it in TABLE_CONSTRAINTS

Tags: information-schema, sql-server-compact, index, constraint

I'm running the following command in my DB:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [UK_NAME1] ON [TABLE1] ([COLUMN1] ASC);
```

Now, I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

And yet I can't find my unique index listed in there.

Am I using the wrong query? What other issue could there be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax, which also allows you to name the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_PersonID UNIQUE (P_Id,LastName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong command to create the unique index. I should have used:

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE1] ADD UNIQUE ([COLUMN1])
```

The only downside is that I can't name it on my own... but its a random name anyway.